# The problem of low fps and high lag in the game and format error in TeamSpeak installation

Tags: graphics, games, format, teamspeak

My system profile
cpu: intel g2020
ram: 4g
gpu: gtx 1060 6g
I am playing dota 2 with this system at lowest setting 40 fps
And I encountered a format error in TeamSpeak installation:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg6RM.png)